# Calculate probability using brute-force method

Tags: probability, bayesian-network

I have to calculate a probability using the following probabilities from a Bayesian network:
$$P(+a)=...$$
$$P(+a|+b)=..., P(+a|¬b)=...$$
$$P(+b|+a)=..., P(+b|¬a)=...$$
$$P(+d|+b)=..., P(+d|¬b)=...$$
$$P(+f|+b,+c)=..., P(+f|¬b,+c)=..., P(+f|¬b,¬c)=...$$
$$P(+g|+c)=..., P(+g|¬c)=...$$

I have to calculate $P(a|+d,+f,¬g)$.

I have no idea about how to do it, but I guess it is something like that:

$$P(a|+d,+f,¬g)=\frac{P(a,+d,+f,¬g)}{P(+d,+f,¬g)}$$

And then, I have to calculate $P(a,+d,+f,¬g)$ and $P(+d,+f,¬g)$ using the previous probabilities. Is that correct?

But the $P(a|$ is confusing me because it hasn't a + or a ¬.

**NOTE:** you don't have to elaborate each formula, only point me to the right direction.

Comment: Please, do not downvote. I can read. Your comment is enough to make me remove the image. Thanks.

Comment: Downvote converted to upvote.  Please note that downvote indicates my personal dislike for text images, since this is *inconsiderate* for those using screen readers and other assistive technologies, notably those with Disorders of Reading and Writing, visually impaired, etc.  Besides, it's *not* searching on search engines like [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bayesian network tells you that the joint distribution factorizes according to
$$P(a,b,c,d,f,g) = P(a)P(b|a)P(c|a) P(d|b)P(f|b,c) P(g|c),$$
So you can compute any truth assignments using the conditional distributions you have presented.

For instance
$$P(+a, \neg b, +c, \neg d, +f, +g) = P(+a)P(\neg b|+ a)P(+ c| + a) P(\neg d| \neg b)P(+ f|\neg b,+c) P(+g|+ c).$$
Note that you have all these probabilities: for those that you do not have explicit, consider the normalization constraint that tells you that $P(\neg E) = 1 - P(E)$.

You have correctly written that 
$$P(a| +d, +f, \neg g) = \frac{P(a,+d,+f,\neg g)}{P(+d,+f,\neg g)}.$$
Note that this is a short-hand that represents two probabilities: $P(+a|+d,+f,\neg g)$ and $P(\neg a|+d,+f,\neg g)$. By normalization, you only need to compute one of them, and the other one follows by $P(+a|+d,+f,\neg g) = 1 - P(\neg a|+d,+f,\neg g)$; so we only look at  $P(+a| +d, +f, \neg g)$.

Now we need observe that the numerator and denominator probability involve a subset of the variables. This means that we must *marginalize.* We need to remove the variables that do not appear using the sum-rule of probability theory:

$P(A) = \sum_B P(A, B).$

In your case, we have that
$$P(+a, +d, +f, \neg g) = \sum_{b,c} P(+a, b, c +d, +f, \neg g),$$
where the summation sign means that we sum over all possible outcomes of $b$, and $c$:
$$P(+a, +d, +f, \neg g) = 
P(+a, +b, +c +d, +f, \neg g) +
P(+a, +b, \neg c +d, +f, \neg g) +
P(+a, \neg b, +c +d, +f, \neg g) +
P(+a, \neg b, \neg c +d, +f, \neg g).
$$
To compute each one of these probabilities, you use the definition of the joint at the beginning of the answer.

Similarly, you can compute $P(\neg a, +d, +f, \neg g)$. Then, you use the same rule to compute
$$P(+d, +f, \neg g) = P(+a, +d, +f, \neg g) + P(\neg a, +d, +f, \neg g).$$

It's a lot of products and sums :) good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand this sentence "We need to remove the variables that do not appear using the sum-rule of probability theory". I think you are saying that to get the probability of A, I have to sum all the probabilities where A appears.

Comment: Quite the opposite, if you want the probability of $A$, but only know the joint $P(A,B)$, then you need to "remove" the $B$ from the joint, to find $P(A)$. You do this by summing the joint over all the possible outcomes of $B$: for instance $P(A) = P(A,+B) + P(A,\neg B)$.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your point: a lot of terms in the summation may disappear; the only ones that matter are the ones where the variable you are interested in appears (together with all the ones they are conditioned upon).

Comment: Thanks. In case of $P(+d, +f, \neg g)$, why don't you use $b$ and $c$? In other words, why do you use only $a$ to calculate it? Thanks.

Comment: I think you have forgotten the $c$ on the first formula.

Comment: Yes I had forgotten a $c$! Regarding $P(+d,+f,\neg g)$, you just need to consider $a$ because we already have $P(a,d,f,g)$: we have already removed $b$ and $c$ from the joint. You can indeed start from the full joint and remove $a$, $b$, and $c$: you will quickly realize that you can group the terms in this huge sum so that you first remove $b$ and $c$, and what you get left is $P(a,d,f,g)$ :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This is my last question, I promise. How can I factorize $ P(+a, +d, +f, \neg g)$? Thanks.

Comment: I'm your second formula: $P(+a, \neg b, +c, \neg d, +f, +g) = P(+a)P(\neg b|+ a)P(+ c| + a) P(\neg d| \neg b)P(+ f|\neg b,+c) P(+g|\neg c).$ You use $\neg c$ in the last probability, $P(+g|\neg c)$,but $c$ is not negative. Is that correct? Thanks.

Comment: @VansFannel $\neg c$ was a typo. Regarding $P(+a, +d, +f, \neg g)$ you don't need to factorize it, you express it as the sum over all possible outcomes of $b$ and $c$ as I showed you; each term in this sum you can factorize using the Bayesian Network. Similarly you can compute $P(\neg a, +d, +f, \neg g)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot of your time and help. Because I'm still don't know how to compute  $P(+d,+f,\neg g)$ I have asked another question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3209185/compute-probability-given-a-bayesian-network.