# Compute probability given a Bayesian Network

Tags: probability, bayesian-network

Having the following Bayesian Network:

```
A -> B, A -> C, B -> D, B -> F, C -> F, C -> G
```

> $$\begin{array}{l} A&\to&B&\to& D\\\downarrow &&\downarrow
> \\ C&\to&F\\\downarrow\\G
> \end{array}$$

With the following probabilities:

$$P(+a)=...$$
$$P(+a|+b)=..., P(+a|¬b)=...$$
$$P(+b|+a)=..., P(+b|¬a)=...$$
$$P(+d|+b)=..., P(+d|¬b)=...$$
$$P(+f|+b,+c)=..., P(+f|¬b,+c)=..., P(+f|¬b,¬c)=...$$
$$P(+g|+c)=..., P(+g|¬c)=...$$

I have to compute this $P(+d, +f, \neg g)$, that I think is:

$$P(+d, +f, \neg g) = P(+a, +d, +f, \neg g) + P(\neg a, +d, +f, \neg g).$$

My question is: **how can I compute each addend?**

I think is:
$$P(+a, +d, +f, \neg g) = P(+a)·P(+d|+b)·P(+f|+b,+c)·P(\neg g,+c)$$

But I'm using $b$ and $c$ that there aren't in $P(+a, +d, +f, \neg g)$.

**NOTE**: This question is related to this one: [Calculate probability using brute-force method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3208267/calculate-probability-using-brute-force-method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to marginalize all the variables from the joint distribution:
$$p(a,d,f,g) = \sum_{b,c}p(a,b,c,d,f,g) = \sum_{b,c} p(a)p(b|a)p(d|b)p(f|b,c)p(g|c).$$

You plug in $+d$, $+f$, and $\neg g$ and you sum for all combinations of $\pm b$ and $\pm c$. When you plug in $+ a$ you get $p(+a,+d,+f,\neg g)$. When you plug in $\neg a$, you get $p(\neg a, +d,+f,\neg g)$. Finally, you sum these two together and you get the required marginal:
$$p(+d,+f,\neg g) =\sum_{a,b,c}p(a)p(b|a)p(c|a)p(+d|b)p(+f|b,c)p(\neg g|c).$$
The sum now runs over all combinations of $\pm a$, $\pm b$, and $\pm c$. Hope this helps!

Comment: You missed a term $$\mathsf P({+}d,{+}f,{\lnot}g)=\sum_{a,b,c} \mathsf P(a)~\mathsf P(b\mid a)~\mathsf P(c\mid a)~\mathsf P({+}d\mid b)~\mathsf P({+}f\mid b, c)~\mathsf P({\lnot} g\mid c)$$

Comment: Yes indeed, corrected!

Comment: Thanks, but if I'm trying to compute $P(a| +d, +f, \neg g) = \frac{P(a,+d,+f,\neg g)}{P(+d,+f,\neg g)}$, and both terms, the numerator and denominator will be the same term. Numerator: $P(+a, +d, +f, \neg g) = \sum_{b,c} P(+a, b, c +d, +f, \neg g)$. Denominator: $P(+a, +d, +f, \neg g) = \sum_{a,b,c} P(a, b, c +d, +f, \neg g),$ I will get that $P(a| +d, +f, \neg g) = 1$, isn't it?

Comment: No, at the numerator the sum only runs over $b$ and $c$; at the denominator it runs over $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Comment: Basically $\mathsf P(+A\mid \text{theRest})=\dfrac{\mathsf P(+A,\text{theRest})}{\mathsf P(+A,\text{theRest})+\mathsf P(\lnot A,\text{theRest})}$